# Attempt to launch Hyperledger Composer app using npm start gives "Cannot find name %participant%" error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, npm-start

I'm following the [Developer Tutorial for creating a Hyperledger Composer solution](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) over at https://hyperledger.github.io/, and I got all the way to the end without a hitch until running into this wall.

For the final step of running the app and webpacking it with Angular (`npm start`), I'm running into the following `Cannot find name` errors, triggered by `inline.bundle.js`.

[image]

After digging around, I discovered that all these offending variables had something in common — they were defined in their respective .cto files using the `import` command. For example, this is what models/manufacturer.cto looks like in the Business Network Definition:

[image]

This is what models/regulator.to looks like:

[image]

The same pattern holds true for all the errors, it cannot find names which are defined in the Business Network using `import`.

I suspected this had something to do with the namespace, but whether I tell composer to compile the app using namespaces or by never using namespaces makes no difference, I get the same errors each time.

I'm new to this so any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This looks similar to this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960487/executing-yo-hyperledger-composer-fails-to-correctly-import-model

Comment: thanks for looking into it @DanSelman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to [v0.12.0](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.12.0) appears to have solved the issue. Yeoman now compiles the web app without any errors. Looks like the bug had already been reported a month ago [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1756), but was just closed a few days ago.